# Quartz Scheduler threads blocked

Tags: sql, oracle, quartz-scheduler

I have java and spring based web application. It is using Quartz scheduler to trigger stored procedure. For few days it was not firing stored procedure, upon inspection/analysis I found that quartz threads are blocked. Here is the thread dump:

"org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-3" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaac40ce800 nid=0x7c85 runnable [0x00000000430cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.t2cParseExecuteDescribe(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CCallableStatement.executeForDescribe(T2CCallableStatement.java:519)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T2CCallableStatement.java:765)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1170)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3339)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3445)
    - locked <0x00000000e2052c30> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CCallableStatement)
    - locked <0x00000000e2053e18> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4394)
    - locked <0x00000000e2052c30> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CCallableStatement)
    - locked <0x00000000e2053e18> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at com.test.server.listener.db.PersistUtil.purge(PersistUtil.java:561)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)

Code to fire stored procedure:

```
try {
    con = dataSource.getConnection();
    cstmt0 = con.prepareCall("{call PURGE_METHOD}");
    cstmt0.execute();
    cstmt0.close();
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    sqle.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(cstmt0 != null){
        try {
            cstmt0.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) { }
    }
    if(con != null){
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) { }
     }
 }
```

How to fix this issue?
Additional info - There are two instances of web applications running.